# Can't print to console in robocode

Tags: java, robocode

I am trying to write anything to Console, but with no luck.

```
System.out.println("abc");
```

Should work, but it is not.
It is my whole code:

```
import robocode.HitWallEvent;
import robocode.Robot;

public class MyRobot extends Robot
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ahead(20);
            System.out.println("Test Test");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onHitWall(HitWallEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("Ouch, I hit a wall bearing " + event.getBearing() + " degrees.");
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Best regards!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Robocode Standard Out

Each bot prints to its own console. To access a bot's console:

- Start a match with your bot
- Click the bot's tag on the panel to the right

[image: Robocode: select bot's tag]

Now you should see something like this that contains whatever messages your bot is printing to standard out.

[image]

This window is also what you would use, should you wish to view what your bot has painted on the battlefield. This is a particularly helpful feature for debugging.

Comment: This is the solution. But Q is almost one year old. I managed to do it back then. :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you are actually able to print something to the console.

But I know you can write data into files which usually should be more useful anyway :).

If you want you can check the sample robot "SittingDuck" there is example code which is using file writers and readers.